# Stored procedure - INSERT INTO and UPDATE in one query

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert

I would like to create a stored procedure. I have 2 databases - one with customers' data and the second one with discount codes. I would like to assign code to each customer. The code can be assigned only once, so I would like to mark the code as 'used' once it is assigned. The codes should be assigned only to those customers that don't have a code assigned.

CUSTOMER_DATABASE:

| CUSTOMER ID | CUSTOMER CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6f73js |
| 2 |  |
| ... | ... |

DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES:

| ID | CODE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6f73js | USED |
| 2 | kdw45s |  |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is it possible to use INSERT INTO and UPDATE in one query? I tried to do this like that, but something is not working. The status changes to 'used' but the codes don't assign.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_DATABASE (CUSTOMER CODE)
SELECT CODE FROM DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES
WHERE STATUS = ''
UPDATE DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES 
SET STATUS = 'Used';
```

Could you please help me write the query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: My DBMS is MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0):

To create the stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure-name> @CUSTOMER_CODE INT
AS
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_DATADASE VALES (@CUSTOMER_CODE)
UPDATE DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES SET STATUS = 'Used' WHERE CODE = @CUSTOMER_CODE
```

To execute it

```sql
EXECTUE <procedure-name> CUSTOMER_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure-name> 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_DATABASE (CUSTOMER_CODE)
        SELECT CODE FROM DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES
        WHERE STATUS = ' '
  
    UPDATE DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES 
    SET STATUS = 'Used';
END
Go
```

Avoid using space in the column name 'CUSTOMER_CODE'.

Replace space with _ underscore symbol.

Comment: Something is still not working. Status updates, but codes don't assign. The column is empty.